# Interface Builder Using auto-layout to Reduce Programming

Tags: interface-builder

## The Layout

- View1
- - ScrollView
- - - View2
- - - - Welcome.png
- - - - "to get start" label
- - - - input
- - - - button

## The Problem

I need `view2` to be >= 30px from the top for small screens (iphone 4) and I need it to be <= 102 for big screens (iphone 6+). I've tried tweaking the constraints and I either get 30px or 102px but never a system that works for both phone sizes. I know how to do this via programming, but how can I do it with just the interface builder?

**Note:**

I've gone the route of using `updateConstraints` on View1 and it works but I'm trying to remove ALL programming.

[image: welcome no-gap]
[image: welcome gap]

Comment: tried size classes? http://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started

Comment: I had but after your comment I gave them another shot and while I haven't exactly got it, I think this is going get me there: http://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started - feel free to leave an answer

Comment: Can't provide a to-the-point answer to the question, however posted a quick starter as the answer. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use size classes for achieving the same. The size classes use a concept of universal storyboards. Universal Storyboards are the first step on your journey towards Adaptive Layout. The same storyboard can now be used for both iPads and iPhones(Landscape/Portrait). There’s no need to keep per-device storyboards in sync with each other – a monotonous process which can be fraught with error. This also saves you a lot of "Programming time", since the screen-size dependency need not be set in code. You can also set different font sizes and similar properties as per the screen size, without separate storyboards/code.

**[This is a good tutorial from RAYWENDERLICH that can get you started.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started)**

Comment: This is EXACTLY the kind of thing I was looking for. It didn't accomplish everything I was looking to do but size classes definitely opened new doors as to how to solve my issue.

Comment: Glad that it helped. :-)